# Making multiple scrollviews respond as one takes out the scrolling behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a view, with four scrollviews inside of it. What I'd like to do is make all these scrollviews respond when one of them is scrolled. I tried to do that through this code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.hpcScrollView.setContentOffset(scrollView.contentOffset, animated: true)
        self.parScrollView.setContentOffset(scrollView.contentOffset, animated: true)
        self.scoreScrollView.setContentOffset(scrollView.contentOffset, animated: true)
        self.holeScrollView.setContentOffset(scrollView.contentOffset, animated: true)
}
```

however, when I apply this, the scrolling "behavior" is taken away. It does still scroll, but there's no bounce, and when I take my finger off the scrollview, it immediately stops scrolling (see gif below)

[image]

Is there a way to make this feel like normal scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not apply the `contentOffset` to the scrollView which is currently scrolling. Changing the `contentOffset` on a currently scrolling view would cause it to stop scrolling and immediately jump to the offset.

```
let scrollableViews = [hpcScrollView, parScrollView, scoreScrollView, holeScrollView]    

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollableViews.forEach { if $0 != scrollView { $0.setContentOffset(scrollView.contentOffset, animated: true) } }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The `scrollViewDidScroll` is getting called whenever we're setting the content offset, which causes the weird scrolling behaviors shown in the gif.

try this instead

```
let scrollableViews = [hpcScrollView, parScrollView, scoreScrollView, holeScrollView]    

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollableViews.forEach { if $0 != scrollView {
        let scrollBounds = $0.bounds
        scrollBounds.origin = scrollView.contentOffset
        $0.bounds = scrollBounds
    } }
}
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/lv4DX Not quite where I wanna go haha, but we're getting there

Comment: Or you could just embed all of them in a single scrollview...
If you're willing to share a minimal working project with me, I'd be happy to to take a look at it.

Comment: take a look at the edit, not the prettiest solution but should work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you reset the originating scroll view, which makes it stop. You need to keep track of the current scroll view the user is interacting with and only update the other scroll views. Otherwise they will all generate scroll events and end up updating each other.

```
// currentScrollView is an object var
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    currentScrollView = scrollView
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == currentScrollView {
        if currentScrollView != self.hpcScrollView {
            self.hpcScrollView.setContentOffset(scrollView.contentOffset, animated: false)
        }
        if currentScrollView != self.parScrollView {
            self.parScrollView.setContentOffset(scrollView.contentOffset, animated: false)
        }
        if currentScrollView != self.scoreScrollView {
            self.scoreScrollView.setContentOffset(scrollView.contentOffset, animated: false)
        }
        if currentScrollView != self.holeScrollView {
            self.holeScrollView.setContentOffset(scrollView.contentOffset, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you must set the `animated` flags to `false`.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/lv4DX Not quite where I wanna go haha, but we're getting there